# Archive Failed / exit status: 65 - iOS fastlane build

Tags: ios, react-native, fastlane

When I try to run my beta lane I get this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHNKq.png)

My staging lane work perfectly however this pre-prod lane isn't executing. Difference between the lanes in the scheme. I can't find the exact issue.
Do you guys have any idea how to solve such an issue?

```
❌  error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ATPAutoteile-ewiwulmkdtysbjegycpawxyttoab/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ATPAutoteileProd/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ATPAutoteile.build/Release-iphoneos/ATPAutoteileProd.build/DerivedSources/Pods-ATPAutoteileProd-checkManifestLockResult.txt'


    duplicate output file '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ATPAutoteile-ewiwulmkdtysbjegycpawxyttoab/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ATPAutoteileProd/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ATPAutoteile.build/Release-iphoneos/ATPAutoteileProd.build/DerivedSources/Pods-ATPAutoteileProd-checkManifestLockResult.txt' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ATPAutoteile-ewiwulmkdtysbjegycpawxyttoab/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ATPAutoteileProd/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ATPAutoteile.build/Release-iphoneos/ATPAutoteileProd.build/Script-B98B4A1A51B148FF9682C9F2.sh (in target 'ATPAutoteileProd' from project 'ATPAutoteile')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[09:52:57]: Exit status: 65
```

I checked [CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock and I have 2 variables there, but I'm not confident if I should delete one or not.

Error from the log file:

```
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ATPAutoteile-ewiwulmkdtysbjegycpawxyttoab/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ATPAutoteileProd/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ATPAutoteile.build/Release-iphoneos/ATPAutoteileProd.build/DerivedSources/Pods-ATPAutoteileProd-checkManifestLockResult.txt'
    note: That command depends on command in Target 'ATPAutoteileProd' (project 'ATPAutoteile'): script phase “Run Script”
    note: That command depends on command in Target 'ATPAutoteileProd' (project 'ATPAutoteile'): script phase “[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock”
```

Update: I think I found the issue. My project.pbxproj file is probably corrupted. One of my colleagues added Detox testing in the app and I think that added a new build step to the production Schema:

```
DE0C3FC267A3918F85ED3A32 /* ShellScript */ = {
    isa = PBXShellScriptBuildPhase;
    buildActionMask = 2147483647;
    files = (
    );
    outputPaths = (
        "$(DERIVED_FILE_DIR)/Pods-ATPAutoteileProd-checkManifestLockResult.txt",
    );
    runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
    shellPath = /bin/sh;
    shellScript = "diff \"${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile.lock\" \"${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock\" > /dev/null\nif [ $? != 0 ] ; then\n    # print error to STDERR\n    echo \"error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.\" >&2\n    exit 1\nfi\n# This output is used by Xcode 'outputs' to avoid re-running this script phase.\necho \"SUCCESS\" > \"${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}\"\n";
    showEnvVarsInLog = 0;
};
```

and this is causing the duplicate issue. I don't have the necessary experience with native programming to solve the issue, can anyone maybe help me out here?

```
Existing build step: 
    A31E9DFB76A71B2800EDF265 /* [CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock */ = {
            isa = PBXShellScriptBuildPhase;
            buildActionMask = 2147483647;
            dependencyFile = "$(DERIVED_FILES_DIR)/$(INPUT_FILE_PATH).d";
            files = (
            );
            inputFileListPaths = (
            );
            inputPaths = (
                "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile.lock",
                "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock",
            );
            name = "[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock";
            outputFileListPaths = (
            );
            outputPaths = (
                "$(DERIVED_FILE_DIR)/Pods-ATPAutoteileProd-checkManifestLockResult.txt",
            );
            runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
            shellPath = /bin/sh;
            shellScript = "diff \"${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile.lock\" \"${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock\" > /dev/null\nif [ $? != 0 ] ; then\n    # print error to STDERR\n    echo \"error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.\" >&2\n    exit 1\nfi\n# This output is used by Xcode 'outputs' to avoid re-running this script phase.\necho \"SUCCESS\" > \"${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}\"\n";
        };
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your errors and code as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].